# Best way to handle one million concurrent socket connections

Tags: sockets, apache-kafka, activemq-classic

**Use case:** We have to develop a backend service (NodeJS) for mobile application which should change the state of mobile app in given time.

**Example:** Audience voting system, once we change the question to vote from the backend it should reflect in the mobile app on real-time.

I have come across many technologies,

- Amazon MQ (Apache ActiveMQ with MQTT) - Problem is this service can't scale beyond a single instance (type: mq.m4.large, 2 vCPU, 8GB). I'm not sure it can handle one million connections and there's no limitation mentioned in the documentation or FAQ.
- Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) - FCM is totally free and so far i did not found any limitation. (with AWS Lambda & DynamoDB)
- Apache Kafka

We're expecting one million connections in given time of period. I need to know what are the best solutions for this use case.

Comment: It's not about 'time period'. How many *concurrent* connections are you expecting? i.e. at the *same* time?

Comment: @EJP I'm expecting near one million concurrent connections at the same time.

Comment: i feel, Kafka is the best choice for this ..please refer this link https://engineering.linkedin.com/kafka/benchmarking-apache-kafka-2-million-writes-second-three-cheap-machines

Answer (score 1):

well am not  sure  about  that  kind of  concurrent requests in nodejs  but  i  think the  following link may be  useful  for you .

[600k concurrent websocket connections on AWS using Node.js](https://blog.jayway.com/2015/04/13/600k-concurrent-websocket-connections-on-aws-using-node-js/)

Comment: I'm using aws elastic beanstalk to handle multiple nodejs application instance. Problem is i want to handle thousand of connections between mobile application and backend. For the costly process i'm also using AWS Lambda functions